# expecting result is not coming from mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join, having

I have following two tables:

```
table: loan
--------------------------------------------------------
 id | advance_id | loan_amount | deposit_amount | date
--------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 22556678 | 5000 | 0 | 2015-02-06
--------------------------------------------------------

table: advance
--------------------------------------------------------
id | advance_id | advance_amount | purpose | date
--------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 22556678 | 20000 | purchase | 2015-01-30
 2 | 22556678 | 10000 | purchase | 2015-01-31
--------------------------------------------------------
```

my code is:

```
SELECT a.advance_id, sum(a.advance_amount) as adv_amount, a.purpose, a.date, sum(l.loan_amount) as loan_amount FROM advance as a INNER JOIN loan as l ON a.advance_id=l.advance_id GROUP BY a.advance_id HAVING sum(l.loan_amount)-sum(l.deposit_amount)>0
```

Explanation:
table 'advance' is a table for taking advance and table 'loan' is a table for loan accounts. Advance can be taken for more than one time for the same purpose (here for purchase a product). Each advance is identified by a advance id. As two advances is taken for the same purpose (here for purchase a product), they will have same advance_id. On the other hand, loan is taken against any advance. Loan also can be taken more than one time against same advance. If any loan will be repaid, it will be inserted in deposit_amount column against the advance_id.

In loan_page.php, loan will only be shown if any loan is unpaid/unadjusted. To identify it, I have to calculate loan and deposit column against same advance id by the following code:

```
GROUP BY a.advance_id HAVING sum(l.loan_amount)-sum(l.deposit_amount)>0
```

Then If any loan is unpaid, I have to identify how much loan is taken against each advance_id. So I have to SELECT the following also:

```
sum(l.loan_amount)
```

my fetched output will be:

```
echo 'Total loan Amount: '.$row['loan_amount'].'<br />';
echo 'Advance ID: '.$row['advance_id'].'<br />';
echo 'Advance Amount: '.$row['adv_amount'].'<br />';
echo 'Purpose of Advance: '.$row['purpose'];
```

Above code for this works well except Total loan Amount is coming as double (here 10000 in this case) although it will be 5000. I think there are mistake in GROUP BY or HAVING clause of my mysql query.

Please let me know, how to correct the code so that sum(l.loan_amount) will be 5000 in this case, not 10000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason loan_amount is double is because you're doing an inner join between the tables using the advance_id. Since the advance_id appears twice in the advance_table, the loan row will appear twice. Visually, the join gives you something like this:

```
| advance | loan |
|    1    |  1   |
|    2    |  1   |
```

So when you preform the aggregation on l.loan_amount, it will be counted twice. To fix this, I would do the aggregation on each table by itself, and then join them together. For example, just get the advance_id and SUM(loan_amount) from the loan table by itself like this:

```
SELECT advance_id, SUM(loan_amount)
FROM loan
GROUP BY advance_id;
```

I noticed your original `HAVING` clause checks for loan_amount - deposit_amount, you can do that condition in the above query:

```
SELECT advance_id, SUM(loan_amount) AS totalLoan
FROM loan
GROUP BY advance_id
HAVING SUM(loan_amount) - SUM(deposit_amount) > 0;
```

Next, preform the necessary aggregation in the advance table by itself, like this:

```
SELECT advance_id, SUM(advance_amount) AS totalAdvance
FROM advance
GROUP BY advance_id;
```

Then, I would join those two tables to get the values you need:

```
SELECT t1.advance_id, t1.totalAdvance, t2.totalLoan
FROM(
  SELECT advance_id, SUM(advance_amount) AS totalAdvance
  FROM advance
  GROUP BY advance_id) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT advance_id, SUM(loan_amount) AS totalLoan
  FROM loan
  GROUP BY advance_id
  HAVING SUM(loan_amount) - SUM(deposit_amount) > 0) t2 ON t2.advance_id = t1.advance_id;
```

**NOTE**

I did not include purpose or date because they are not consistent in the advance table. You will have to consider each case. What if the purpose of the two rows were different? The dates are different, so which date do you need returned, if any? Once you know that, you can add them into this query, likely in the 'advance' subquery.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88ce1/4) example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bring the tables together using `union all` rather than `join`.  Or, alternatively, aggregate before the join.

Here is the `union all` version:

```
SELECT advance_id,
       sum(advance_amount) as adv_amount,
       max(purpose) as purpose,
       min(date) as date,
       sum(loan_amount) as loan_amount
FROM ((SELECT a.advance_id,
              a.advance_amount,
              a.purpose,
              a.date,
              NULL as loan_amount,
              NULL as deposit_amount
       FROM advance
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT l.advance_id, NULL, NULL, l.date, loan_amount, deposit_amount
       FROM loan l
      )
     ) al
GROUP BY advance_id
HAVING sum(loan_amount) - sum(deposit_amount) > 0;
```

Comment: How to aggregate before join?

Comment: I want to use join in this case